# Monitoring MarkLogic Database Backups

Tags: marklogic

Can someone provide some inputs on how I can monitor daily backups?

I am looking for a monitoring system which notifies the user when the backup operation has failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backups (as well as other system events) log warnings and errors into both the file based error log (/Logs/ErrorLog.txt) and the system log (syslog on linux/unix, Windows event log on windows).

There are many tools available for log file 'tailing' and alerting -- many good ones are open source and free.  That would be my first suggestion.

For a more active programmatic implementation you can use the admin: API's (XQuery, JavaScript or Rest) to query the backup status and validate backups.
For a place to start look at
https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:database-backup-status

Comment: Thank you for the response.There are various errors that get logged into ErrorLog.txt. Example :  Error: ScheduledBackupTask::run: public-search Error: XDMP-NODIR: No such directory: Does every Failed Backup has the "Error: ScheduledBackupTask::run" ?? Can you suggest one open source tool for tailing and alerting. Thanks in advance.